# Reading files by num without saving in list

Tags: java, android

I create Service where filenames read by `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/defaultpath").list()` and save only names in massive, but it can be very much files in dir. Does exist other method to get file by its num in folder?

(P.s. I've seen that mediafiles can be readen by URI, but I' mot sure how to use this. May be I shoud create SQL table?)

Comment: If file names in specific format like file1,file2,file3...., loop file name is a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.nio.file.Files::list(Path)` ([javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/file/Files)).  This returns a lazily populated `Stream<Path>` that lists the entries in a directory.  There are also `walk` and `walkTree` methods that can recursively traverse a directory tree.